# Set cache-control header to public

Tags: caching, cdn, processor

I know its missing a point of having Sitecore CMS, however we need to put a site behind Azure CDN. We do not care about personalization, analytics etc. Is there any out of box way to set cache-control header to public, max age and ETag for 'everything', instead of just static files, media etc. Is there a processor I can extend to achieve this? Sitecore version 8.2 on VM. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cristi answer pointed me to right direction, however at the end I extended GetPageRenderingProcessor.

```
  public class CustomBrowserCaching : GetPageRenderingProcessor
   {
      public override void Process(GetPageRenderingArgs args)
      {
         //Item currentItem;

         Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
         Profiler.StartOperation("Update browser caching headers.");
         HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
         Item currentItem = PageContext.CurrentOrNull.Item;
         if (context == null) return;

         SetCacheHeaders(currentItem, context);
         if (currentItem != null)
            SetUpdateHeaders(currentItem, context);
         Profiler.EndOperation();
      }

      private static void SetUpdateHeaders(Item currentItem, HttpContext context)
      {
         DateTime date = currentItem.Statistics.Updated;
         if (date > DateTime.UtcNow)
         {
            date = DateTime.UtcNow;
         }
         context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(date);
      }

      private static void SetCacheHeaders(Item item, HttpContext context)
      {
         if (Context.Site == null)
            return;

         context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
         var ts = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
         context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(ts);
         context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
         var date = item.Statistics.Updated;
         if (date > DateTime.Now)
         {
            date = DateTime.Now;
         }
         context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(date);
         context.Response.Cache.SetETag(item.Statistics.Revision);
      }
   }
```

Patched these configs:

```
     <setting name="DisableBrowserCaching">
        <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
     </setting>

     <setting name="MediaResponse.Cacheability">
        <patch:attribute name="value">Public</patch:attribute>
     </setting>
```

Attached added config to zzz folder:

```
 <mvc.getPageRendering>
    <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetPageRendering.GetLayoutRendering, Sitecore.Mvc']" type="Your.Namespace.CustomBrowserCaching, Your.Assembly.Name">
    </processor>
 </mvc.getPageRendering>
```

Many of this has been taken from here https://www.flux-digital.com/blog/disabling-private-cache-sitecore-pages-not-working-sitecore-8-1-8-2/ .

Answer (score 1):

In App_Config/Sitecore.config there is a processor defined for setting browsercaching `<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.BrowserCaching, Sitecore.Kernel" />`

You can take a look at its implementation in `sitecore.kernel.dll` and you could add your own custom implementation by overriding it

```
public override void Process(RenderLayoutArgs args)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, nameof (args));
      Profiler.StartOperation("Update browser caching headers.");
      PageContext page = Context.Page;
      if (page == null || page.Page == null)
        return;
      BrowserCaching.SetCacheHeaders(page.Page);
      if (Context.Item != null)
        BrowserCaching.SetUpdateHeaders(Context.Item, page.Page);
      Profiler.EndOperation();
    }
```